# OpenCV : Decide size of structuring element as per the dimension of the image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

This is the first time I am posting, hope I manage to make my problem clear to you all.

I have a binary image on which some text is written in vertical/horizontal alignment. I need to apply morphological operation on these images for which I need to give the structuring element with some size.
My problem is that I need to apply different size structuring element for morphological operations.

I have tried the following approach

1. Draw a bounding rectangle around the nonZero pixels in the image and apply condition based on its height and width
   My code is something like :

   ```
   Mat Points;
   findNonZero(imgSrc, Points);
   Rect rect = boundingRect(Points);
   rectangle(imgSrc, rect.tl(), rect.br(), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
   if (rect.width > rect.height){
           elementHor = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(45, 7));
           elementVer = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 35));
   }
   else{
           elementHor = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(31, 7));
           elementVer = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 35));
   }
   morphologyEx(imgSrc, imgSrc, CV_MOP_CLOSE, elementVer);
   morphologyEx(imgSrc, imgSrc, CV_MOP_CLOSE, elementHor);
   ```
2. Draw a rotated rectangle and and then do the same procedure for condition check using its width and height.
   Code :

   ```
   std::vector<cv::Point> points;
   cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator it = imgSrc.begin<uchar>();
   cv::Mat_<uchar>::iterator end = imgSrc.end<uchar>();
   for (; it != end; ++it)
       if (*it)
           points.push_back(it.pos()); 

   cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));
   if (box.size.width > box.size.height){
       elementHor = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(45, 7));
       elementVer = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 35));
   }
   else{
       elementHor = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(31, 7)); 
       elementVer = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 35));
   }
   morphologyEx(imgSrc, imgSrc, CV_MOP_CLOSE, elementVer);
   morphologyEx(imgSrc, imgSrc, CV_MOP_CLOSE, elementHor);
   ```

The problem is that in most of the cases the horizontal aligned text has a rectangle with height greater than width and vice-versa, therefore incorrect structuring size is applied and hence the system fails to join the correct contours in morphological operation.

Kindly suggest some alternative or improvement needed in my code to rectify the same.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Why do you think that you need to adjust your SEs based on the direction of the text? Also,  the difference between the two sets of SEs you select from is very small. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes that's intentional. I am trying to get the contour from an image. It is required to provide different SEs since keeping small kernel size does not connect all characters written horizontally therefore i need to give a larger value for this. However I cannot keep larger values for vertically aligned text because I don't want to join the text written parallel to vertically aligned text.